# Grub doesn't show up when I Reboot, works fine if I shut down and boot up

Tags: 16.04, grub2, reboot

I am using GRUB as a dual boot manager for choosing between Ubuntu and Windows 10, but I am currently having a small problem with it. It doesn't work when I reboot Ubuntu (it boots Ubuntu automatically again), but it works perfectly if I shut it down and turn it on again. Any solutions?

Comment: we'll need little bit more details, are you on Legacy or UEFI?

Comment: just checked to be sure: UEFI